# How to export a second variable in addition to a default

Tags: typescript

I have in file app.ts:

```
import admin from "./admin";
```

and in file admin.ts:

```
import * as express from "express"
const router = express.router();
var anotherVariable;
...
export default router;
//want to export anotherVariable too
```

How do I also export anotherVariable from admin.ts and how will the corresponding import statements be like in app.ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export a variable, constant, function or class just add an `export` in front of it:

```
export let anotherVariable = '...';
export const anotherConstant = '...';
// ...
```

To import another variable together with an `default` export from another file, you need to use another syntax to give your `default` export an alias.

For example import your variable inside your `app.ts` file like this:

```
import { default as admin, anotherVariable } from './admin';
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. When I used the above, why can't I update `anotherVariable` in app.ts? It says `Cannot assign to 'anotherVariable' because it is not a variable`. What sort of programming construct is it then?

Comment: Imports are considered constants, only the module that exports them can change them, which then propagates to all modules that import them. To modify a variable from another file you could wrap it within a class and declaring it as an static member.

Answer (score 1):

You can export other variables along with a default export:

```
import * as express from "express"
const router = express.router();    
export var anotherVariable = 42;
export default router;
```

And import it using:

```
import admin, {anotherVariable} from "./admin";
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you share where you find this syntax of `import`?  I spent hours on the Handbook and it was time lost.

Comment: Not sure if it is in the TS docs, but this is actually valid ES syntax. I found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2440) issue related to TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be the use of tuples. (see [Basic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html))

```
var var1;
var var2;
var t = [var1, var2];
```